# Why does it print array([ ]) when in a list when using an array to iterate and pull elements from?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Looking to see if I could use comprehensions or array operators, instead of for loops.

```
import numpy as np

a=[[1,2],[3,4]]

b=np.array(a)

c=[[x*z for x in z] for z in b[0:1]]

print(c)
```

> OUTPUT = [[array([1, 2]), array([2, 4])]]

I want a list or array = [2,12]

I can convert list to 1D array after.
Where it is first element * second element for each row in array.

I want it to work on a general case for any 2 dimensional array.

Comment: Why are you using list comprehensions to work with your `numpy.ndarray` objects? Just use lists. Note, you should **always** use a generic [python] tag for python questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the [prod](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.prod.html) function in numpy.

```
from numpy import prod

a = [[1,2],[3,4]]
b = [prod(x) for x in a] 
print(b)
```

Output:

```
[2,12]
```

Comment: Why? Why use numpy with lists?

Comment: I could also use math or the reduce function, but I find this to be the easiest way.

Comment: **But why use `list`** objects? That doesn't make any sense. If you are going to use `numpy`, then *use `numpy.ndarray`* objects, or else that defeats the entire purpose. If `a` were an `numpy.ndarray`, then you could simply do `a.prod(axis=1)`

Comment: Because that is what the OP is asking in his question. He is not asking is there a more efficient way to solve the problem but if there was a way to do so for any 2-D array which is a list and not a numpy array. You are correct in a sense, but I argue that it does not defeat the purpose of using numpy since it shows the versatility of the numpy package. Plus it is in the relatively same format that the OP tried to solve the problem with in the first step - using numpy and list comprehension. But yes I agree, making a numpy array would be easier.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the action - step by step:

```
In [170]: b.shape                                                               
Out[170]: (2, 2)
In [171]: b[0:1]                                                                
Out[171]: array([[1, 2]])              # (1,2) array
In [172]: [z for z in b[0:1]]                                                   
Out[172]: [array([1, 2])]              # iteration on 1st, size 1 dimension
In [173]: [[x for x in z] for z in b[0:1]]                                      
Out[173]: [[1, 2]]
In [174]: [[x*z for x in z] for z in b[0:1]]                                    
Out[174]: [[array([1, 2]), array([2, 4])]]
```

So you are doing `[1*np.array([1,2]), 2*np.array([1,2])]`

With the `b[0:1]` slicing you aren't even touching the 2nd row of `b`.

But a simpler list comprehension does:

```
In [175]: [i*j for i,j in b]     # this iterates on the rows of b                                               
Out[175]: [2, 12]
```

or

```
In [176]: b[:,0]*b[:,1]                                                         
Out[176]: array([ 2, 12])
```

Comment: Than you very much really explained it and I was able to see so many areas where I could simply my code.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question in parts.

- 1. Why does it print array([ ])... ?

The numpy array you use is a class with a `__repr__` or a `__str__` method, which decides what you see, when you have it as an argument in a `print` statement.

In numpys array case, something along the lines of:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return self.__class__.__name__ + "(" + repr(self.array) + ")"
```

- 2 ... when in a list using an array...

The list or dict calls the child elements `__repr__` methods in its `__repr__` method.

- 3. ...and pull elements from?

in your inner `x*z` you are multiplying `x`, a number (1 or 2) with `z` a 1x2 array (`b[0:1] = array([[1, 2]])`). Which has an array as a result, which is the array of itself, multiplied by each of its elements as a scalar (`[[1*1, 1*2]], [2*1, 2*2]]`)

Some other solution for your problem (but probably the already mentioned prod while for sure be much faster ;)):

```
import numpy as np

a=[[1,2],[3,4]]

b=np.array(a)

c=[[z1*z2] for z1, z2 in b]

print(c)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just multiply the first column with the second one:

```
c = b[:, 0] * b[:, 1]
```

Or you can use `np.multiply`:

```
c = np.multiply.reduce(b[:, :2], axis=1)
```